# React Redux onClick wait for actions to finish

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using React and Redux to build my app.

I have a case where one component (call it LeadForm) dispatches 'validate' and certain other elements react upon it. If validate is true for them they validate themselves and dispatch then error true/false. Then, dependent if there is an error or not, the LeadForm goes to another state or waits to solve the errors.

Some code:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (validate) {
    validate.forEach((element) => {
      store.dispatch(validateElement(element, true));
    });
    console.log(store.getState().error);
    if (goToState) {
      store.dispatch(changeState(goToState));
    }
  } else {
    store.dispatch(changeState(goToState));
  }
};
```

And the elments validating them self and dispatching error if necessary:

```
const Error = ({ validate, selects, output, id, errorMessage }) => {
  let error = null;
  if (!selects[output] && validate) {
    error = (
      <div className={cn('row', 'error')}>
        <H4>{errorMessage}</H4>
      </div>
    );
    // Set error 
      store.dispatch(setError(id, true));
  }
  return error;
};
```

The problem is actually simple -> you see the console.log(store.getState().error). This gets called too early and there are no errors even tough the other elements indicate errors after validating. So i somehow need to wait till the other elements finished their validation.

Why do i do it like this? I'm building a Landing page management system where i can glue components together via a backend interface.

Comment: Does the validation happen asynchronously? Also, what is `validate`? An array? where does it come from?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The validation does not happen asnychronously - so there is no need to validate something with the server yet.

Validate is basically an object containing the components that need to be validated (e.g. SelectBox_2).

If this switches to true the components need to validate themself.

Comment: You can't use forEach on an object..